# How can I retrive To Receipt from Email Entity in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Hi I have an Email and I retrive the information of Email Entity using Below code

```cs
Email email = _context.EmailSet.Where(p => p.ActivityId == new Guid("448FF815-17B7-E211-9FDB-B4B52F67D694")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now i have all attribute of Email Entity but how can i get To Receipt from this email.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309512.aspx) article from Microsoft all properties that the email entity has. One property is **To** that is of type ActivityParty.